# Escribir archivo en Kotlin no guarda el primer registro

Tags: android, android-studio, archivo, kotlin

Estoy intentando guardar un array list de mensajes en un archivo. Cuando intento hacerlo no se guarda el primer registro.

Mi código es:

```
val chatfile = File(MyApp.applicationContext().filesDir, "${user_id}-${conversacion.sender}-short.json")
                    if (chatfile.exists()) {
                        val contents = chatfile.readText()
                        val array: List<Message> =
                            gson.fromJson(contents, kotlin.Array<Message>::class.java).toList()
                        val arrayList = ArrayList(array.toList())
                        arrayList.add(0, Message(conversacion.unique_id, conversacion.sender, conversacion.receiver, conversacion.nickname, conversacion.message, conversacion.send_at, false, conversacion.image, conversacion.latitude, conversacion.longitude, conversacion.viewType, conversacion.messageType))
                        val json: String = gson.toJson(arrayList.filterNotNull()).replace("\\n", "\n")
                        chatfile.writeText(json)
                    } else {
                        val array: List<Message> = emptyList()
                        val arrayList = ArrayList(array.toList())
                        arrayList.add(Message(conversacion.unique_id, conversacion.sender, conversacion.receiver, conversacion.nickname, conversacion.message, conversacion.send_at, false, conversacion.image, conversacion.latitude, conversacion.longitude, conversacion.viewType, conversacion.messageType))
                        val json: String = gson.toJson(arrayList.filterNotNull()).replace("\\n", "\n")
                        chatfile.writeText(json)
                    }
```

La parte de (if chatfile.exists) guarda el mensaje, pero el "else" sólo crea un archivo vacío y no guarda el mensaje.

Estoy haciendo algo mal?

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Please translate your question; otherwise it will be closed. You have posted a question on stack overflow in Spanish, if you look for the page in English you can go [here](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Gracias, lo he cambiado a español